# Can I use .". if I want both to end a sentence and to indicate that there was a period ending the sentence that I just quoted?

Tags: quotation-marks, periods, end-punctuation

For example:

In the original publication, the last sentence of the Introduction is: “I love dogs.”. This sentence should be replaced by: “I love cats.”.

Comment: In typical American English usage, it would be correct to write "I love cats." British usage rules would prefer ending your sentence with "I love cats". The original punctuation does not come into play unless it is noteworthy, as a question mark or exclamation point would be. Periods are not noteworthy punctuation.

Comment: @RobJarvis No, that's a misconception. UK style is conditional, not absolute. Since the sentence **ends** with a period, UK style says to put the period inside the final quotation mark. You can refer to page 16 of [the University of Oxford Style Guide](https://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/media_wysiwyg/University%20of%20Oxford%20Style%20Guide.pdf) (PDF) for complete guidance: "Place any punctuation which does not belong to the quote outside the quotation marks (except closing punctuation if the end of the quote is also the end of the sentence)."

Comment: This is a matter of style, and of anachronism.  60 or so years ago you'd have `.".`, but the "rules" changed to eliminate one of the dots.  Which one is eliminated depends on several factors.

Comment: Thank you, @JasonBassford, I now remember learning something about the conditional rules in UK punctuation long ago. I stand corrected.